Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a surjective function of class $\mathcal{C}^1$
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a surjective function of class $\mathcal{C}^1$.
i) Show that $n\geq m$.
ii) Let $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $rank(Df(p))=m.$
Show that there are open neighborhoods $Z$ of $p$ and $W$ of $f (p)$ and a function $g:W\rightarrow Z$ of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ with $g (f (p)) = p$ such that $f\circ g = id$.
I was able to make the first statement.
Can anyone help me with a tip for the second statement?
Things I thought of were the following:
If $pos(Df(p))=m$ this would imply that the determinant of the Jacobian of the matrix mxm would be non-zero. So could I use the inverse function theorem on f restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is that right?

Have you seen the proof of implicit function theorem?

I only read the demonstration for the particular case $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
For the general case I still need to read it, why?

Check out for instance Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" theorem 9.28. You should be able to adapt the proof to solve your problem.
